# update Alpinejs binding when Livewire Competent re-renders

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire form that user-selected date then shows available timeslots for that date via a select options box.

So when the user selects add to cart I just need to past the id of the timeslot. I'm trying to reduce the ajax calls therefore I was wanting to just use AlphineJS binding.

**My livewire blade code.**

```
<div class="col-span-6" x-data="{ selectedSession: $el.querySelector('option').value }">
        <label for="session" class="block text-sm text-gray-700 font-semibold">Select Time</label>
        <select id="session" x-model="selectedSession" name="session">
           @foreach ($sessionsForDay as $session)
             <option :value="{{ $session->id }}" value="{{ $session->id }}"  @if ($loop->first) Selected @endif>
                {{ $session->name() }} - 
             </option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
        <p x-text="selectedSession"></p>
    </div>
```

On page load everything is fine. x-data is getting the currently selected (first) value but when livewire updates $sessionsForDay and re-renders the options fields, AlpineJS doesn't update the id and will show the old ID. If I then select a new time it will then update.

I know livewire has a JS hook but just doesn't feel like the best way for something so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Livewire, I wouldn't worry about your ajax calls. Livewire handles them very well.

Anyhow, how is `$sessionForDay` getting updated by Livewire? There is no direct bind to it, since you're using Alpine's `x-model` and not Livewire's `wire:model`. If you had been using a full Livewire code, I would have suggested [`@entangle`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#extracting-blade-components).

Since you are using Alpine, your code is fine for it to work. Alpine has an onchange for the select, and will update the x-model value based on the selected option. You don't need the `:value` attribute on the `option` tag, and you don't need the selector on your `x-data` tag.

```html
<div class="col-span-6" x-data="{ selectedSession: '{{$sessionsForDay->first()->id}}' }">
    <label for="session" class="block text-sm text-gray-700 font-semibold">Select Time</label>
    <select id="session" x-model="selectedSession" name="session">
       @foreach ($sessionsForDay as $session)
         <option value="{{ $session->id }}"  @if ($loop->first) selected @endif>
            {{ $session->name() }} - 
         </option>
       @endforeach
    </select>
    <p x-text="selectedSession"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Yinci, Wasn't exactly the way I was thinking about it but you way is Allot cleaner and works. My brain was just trying to over complicate it and yeah I am using livewire to handle the ajax calls which is how $sessionForDay is getting updated. I already had the session ID in the view and didnt want to make another ajax call just to get that id in the href of the button. thats why I wanted it in AlpineJS.

Comment: What to do when there is nothing to entangle. I just want alpine to re-update classes once the component is re-rendered.

Comment: @OzanKurt Really depends on your code structure. Livewire allows [browser events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser) that potentially allow you to call a function or inline code. Alpine allows catching [custom events](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#custom-events) really easy!